# Mulesoft can't find OPTIONS request listener

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft, anypoint-platform

I made an API in Mulesoft, that i need to consume from Angular frontend. GET requests work fine, but when I try to send POST/DELETE requests, it gets an error while sending OPTIONS request (response not having cors headers, while cors is set up properly). When i add one of my endpoints on a certant route to accept OPTIONS, it works fine. Can i somehow create a global listener for every OPTIONS request, sent on any route. HTTP connector code bellow.

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="8d79948b-c780-43eb-b7d1-41235210a0ff" basePath="/api" >
    <http:listener-connection host="localhost" port="8081" protocol="HTTP" />
    <http:listener-interceptors >
        <http:cors-interceptor >
            <http:origins >
                <http:origin url="http://localhost:4200" accessControlMaxAge="30000">
                <http:allowed-methods>
                    <http:method methodName="GET" />
                    <http:method methodName="POST" />
                    <http:method methodName="DELETE" />
                    <http:method methodName="OPTIONS" />
                  <http:method methodName="PUT" />
                </http:allowed-methods>
                <http:allowed-headers >
                  <http:header headerName="Content-Type" />
                  <http:header headerName="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" />
                  <http:header headerName="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
              </http:allowed-headers>
              <http:expose-headers />
            </http:origin>

            </http:origins>
        </http:cors-interceptor>
    </http:listener-interceptors>
</http:listener-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my configuration, you need to add expose headers:

```
<http:listener-config name="agentportal-httpListenerConfig">
    <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    <http:listener-interceptors >
        <http:cors-interceptor allowCredentials="false">
            <http:origins >
                <http:origin url="http://localhost:4200" accessControlMaxAge="30000" >
                    <http:allowed-methods >
                        <http:method methodName="OPTIONS" />
                        <http:method methodName="GET" />
                        <http:method methodName="POST" />
                    </http:allowed-methods>
                    <http:allowed-headers >
                        <http:header headerName="Content-Type" />
                        <http:header headerName="Authorization" />
                        <http:header headerName="Accept" />
                    </http:allowed-headers>
                    <http:expose-headers >
                        <http:header headerName="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
                        <http:header headerName="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" />
                        <http:header headerName="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" />
                    </http:expose-headers>
                </http:origin>

            </http:origins>
        </http:cors-interceptor>
    </http:listener-interceptors>
</http:listener-config>
```